# stm32f103 board not blinking

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, gpio

I cant get my new stm32f103c8t6 board to blink a simple led. I have tried everything. I have written bare metal directly to the registers and also used GPIO libraries but its still not working. I am using keil. my led is connected on a breadboard across a 1k resistor . I have also tested the voltage across the output pin but its insignificant. What could be wrong please ? code below ...

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

void delay(int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {

    }

}
int main(void)
{

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

    /* Configure PD0 and PD2 in output pushpull mode */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_2;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* To achieve GPIO toggling maximum frequency, the following  sequence is mandatory. 
     You can monitor PD0 or PD2 on the scope to measure the output signal. 
     If you need to fine tune this frequency, you can add more GPIO set/reset 
     cycles to minimize more the infinite loop timing.
     This code needs to be compiled with high speed optimization option.  */
    while (1)
    {
        /* Set PD0 and PD2 */
        GPIOA->BSRR = 0x00000005;
        delay(1000000);
        /* Reset PD0 and PD2 */
        GPIOA->BRR = 0x00000005;
        delay(1000000);

    }
}
```

Comment: You initialized `GPIOD` but you are using `GPIOA`....

Comment: Probably your delay function does not produce code due to optimizer. BTW is not the way to do delays....

Comment: YEA, i corrected the GPIOD error still not working

Comment: 1) The STlib/HAL is just bloatware. It has no advantage, but multiple disadvantages. Don't use it. 2) `delay` is likely ineffective. 3) Write the registers from the debugger for an initial test of the hardware.

Comment: Sorry Olaf, but looks like your have some real programming issues in your life to say that. Or you never used this if you are saying that.

Comment: this is to some extent a duplicate of your other question.  the bare metal direct approach was just fine.   your delay is probably not working you can test that by getting rid of the while loop all together, depending on how you wired up the led you can just do the BSRR write of 0x00000005 and then while(1) continue or return if your bootstrap tolerates it.  Or BSRR write of 0x00050000 and then while(1) continue; or return.  force the pin high or low and just leave it there, does the led light up, if not then blinking is not going to work.

Comment: if you get it to go on lets say with bsrr 0x00000005, then recompile with bsrr 0x00050000 does the led stay off?  If you have a debugger (openocd with a telnet connect) you can directly write all of these registers manually and see if you can make the led go on or off and confirm it is not the register accesses that are the problem.

Comment: have you disassembled the binary to see if it is the bootstrap or linker script or vector table that is the problem?

Comment: @old_timer i have managed to get the led on but it doesnt blink, even with the new delay function pasted below.

Comment: can you force it off?

Comment: while (1)
       {
  delay(1000000);
        /* Set PD0 and PD2 */
          GPIOA->BSRR = 0x00000005;
           delay(1000000);
   /* Reset PD0 and PD2 */
        GPIOA->BRR  = 0x00000005;
  delay(1000000);
    
        }

Comment: it just keeps blinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

Wrong delay implementation and compiler optimizes code out:

```
void delay(volatile int a) {
    //Added volatile in a and in i
    for (volatile int i = 0; i < a; i++);
}
```

Wrong initialization as in your case. You initialized `GPIOD` but use `GPIOA`.

Comment: Instead of direct register write, use `GPIO_WritePin` function for test. Make sure you work with `GPIOA` since you enabled GPIOA clock.

Comment: yea, the gpio problem solved it , but the delay is not working, what could be wrong in the delay function ?

Comment: i tried it , but it doesnt, should there be anything after the for loop ?\

Comment: the led doesnt blink , just keeps glowing even with a =1000000

Comment: less than 100ms if clock is set as it should be.

Comment: Thanks alot , i have corrected the issue, appreciate the sarcasm :)

Comment: I have one last favor to ask, could you please check out my question at " stm32f103 memory addressing. I tried bare metal addressing but the code douldnt run . i would be very grateful

Comment: I don't see a question. Btw..please mark answer as correct.

Comment: just search it in the search box, it should apperar , or check my profile please :)

Comment: @ched : The STM32 is well supplied with hardware timers, and Cortex-M has a core system clock too, either of these would be better and more accurate than a simple busy loop.

Comment: @tilz0R : *"...if clock is set as it should be."* - How do you know what clock frequency this particular design runs at? The STM32 supports multiple clock sources and the PLL can be programmed to a wide range.  A design may use particular frequencies for a variety of reasons such as USB clock accuracy, EMC compliance, power saving, or use of an oscillator shared with some other device.   Ultimately you have no idea how long the loop will take, and it will need adjusting for each new design the code is used on. This is an unfortunately common but ill-advised idiom.

Comment: Im electronic ejgineer too, Clifford. F103 is supposed to work at 72MHz. If you dont need that speed, you take another mcu.

Comment: Ok now I understand: _electronic engineer_ talking about firmware.... crystal ... ;)